# Duplicate questions with MO.SE?

Tags: discussion, questions, exact-duplicates

I've asked today the following question [What is fairly new theorem one can teach (and prove) to an undergraduate student?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/686/what-is-fairly-new-theorem-one-can-teach-and-prove-to-an-undergraduate-student)

As @quid mentioned in his comment, a very similar question was asked on MO.SE, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/129759/modern-mathematical-achievements-accessible-to-undergraduates.

If there hadn't been an upvote or answer, I would've deleted the question. I wasn't able to vote for closing since closing as a duplicate with another SE site isn't possible.

How should we deal with such questions (now and in the future)?

Comment: This got asked for math.SE instead of MO.SE but I think this is basically the same http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/7/what-constitutes-a-duplicate-to-an-m-se-thread And, I answered the question in accordance with what was said there. That is, while I mentioned the examples there, in my answer here I tried to stress an educational aspect. Had I answered on MO, I would have framed the answer somewhat differently.